# How to use number loop in Picker Wheel

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know this might be basic, but my brain is stuck. I'm trying to generate numbers 1-100 in my picker wheel. But I forgot how to actually add the for loop so it will show 1-100. I'm confused because it only allows string values to be entered so don't know how to actually do that without writing them all out one by one.

Thank you in advance.

```
const PickerComp = () => {
const [daysGone, setDaysGone] = useState()


const nr = 1
const numbers = `${nr}` 
//for ( let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
            selectedValue={daysGone}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setDaysGone(itemValue, itemIndex)}>
            <Picker.Item label={numbers} value="1" />
      </Picker>
      <Text>{daysGone}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```